# Prevent JSON objects from rendering if certain conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I have two DataTables: "Admissions" and "Special". They contain JSON data that's being rendered properly.

I want to make it so that if certain data from Admissions are present, then they will *not* be rendered to Admissions but to Special instead.

Any thoughts about how to go about this? I figured that if I can get data to be shown in the Special table, then I can do the reverse for the Admissions table later on.

#### Here's a JSON snippet that should hopefully clarify things:

```
{
    "d": {
      "results": [
        {
         ...
         "p_h_v": "" // ------------ doesn't meet conditions, gets rendered to Admissions
         ...
        },
        {
         "p_h_v": "Yes" // ---------- meets conditions, gets rendered to Special instead
         ...
```

#### JS snippet for Special table:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import admissData from '../JSON/admiss.json';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

function loadAdmiss() {
    let admissText = admissData.d.results.map(function(val) {
        if (val.p_h_v.includes("")) return ""; // ------- I'm thinking that I should include code right here, but I'm not sure
        return {
            "PHV": val.p_h_v,
            ... // ----- irrelevant data
        }
    })

    $('#phv-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "PHV" },
                ...
        ],
        ... // ----- irrelevant data
```

---

#### Update:

```
function loadAdmiss() {
    let admissText = admissData.d.results.filter(val => {
        if (val.p_h_v !== "") {
            return {
                "PHV": val.p_h_v
                ...
            }
        }
    })

    $('#phv-table').DataTable({
```

Comment: What is your question actually ? Where did you fail here ?

Comment: I wanted to know how to exclude certain JSON objects if certain conditions are met. i.e. If `"p_h_v": "Yes"`, then it gets rendered to the Special table. If not, then it gets rendered to the Admissions table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the following

```
admissText = admissData.d.results.filter(x => x.p_h_v !== "");
```

It will return you the `results` array with elements that has some value in `p_h_v`

Sample admissText value:

```
[
    {
        "p_h_v": "some text"
        ...
    },
    {
        "p_h_v": "some text"
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

`.filter()` can just filter out some data and return result. You can't return another array. For that you will need `.map()`.

```
admissText = admissData.d.results.map(x => {
        if (x.p_h_v !== "") {
            return {
                "PHV": x.p_h_v
            }
        }
    }).filter(x => x !== undefined);
```

Sample admissText value:

```
[
    {
        "PHV": "some text"
    }
    ...
]
```

Comment: Would it be something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bocrgm2f/ ? I'll also post an update into the question body